# iOS import dictionary from one plist to another

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, email, plist

I'm trying to get my app to import settings into itself from an email. The way this will work is users will send a `settings.properties` file to themselves which is really a `plist` that looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Viewer</key>
    <array>
        <string>username</string>
        <string>password</string>
        <string>http://www.example.com</string>
        <string>/example</string>
        <string>urlparam=whatever</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

I can open and read the file correctly using `NSLog`, but I need to import the `dictionary` into my apps main Data.plist without overwriting what's already there, and then delete the imported plist from the Documents/Inbox folder.

Any clues would be great :)

//Edit

I've updated my method based on comments below. It now only works if the file Data.plist already exists in my apps documents directory. So I need to create it if it doesn't exist and then add in my .properties file..

This is the code I'm using currently.

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
if (url){

        NSDictionary *openedDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:url];

        // get paths from root direcory
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        // get documents path
        NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        // get the path to our Data/plist file
        NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];
        NSDictionary *originalDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

        NSMutableDictionary *newDictionary = [originalDictionary mutableCopy];
        for (NSString *key in openedDictionary) {
            if (!newDictionary[key]) {
                newDictionary[key] = openedDictionary[key];
            }
        }

        [newDictionary writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];

    }
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:url error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"error while deleting: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if your data structure is wrong. You have dictionary not array for settings, it more readable and it will be simpler for you to parse it and not make a mistake.

I would suggest editing your file to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>username</key>
    <string>username_value</string>
    <key>password</key>    
    <string>password_value</string>
    <key>url</key>
    <string>www.example.com</string>
    <key>url2</key>
    <string>/example</string>
    <key>urlparam</key>
    <string>urlparam=whatever</string>
</dict>
```

Converting plist to dictionary is very simple.

```
NSData* plistData = [source dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *error;
NSPropertyListFormat format;
NSDictionary* plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistData mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable format:&format errorDescription:&error];
```

You should read more about [Serializing a Property List](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/SerializePlist/SerializePlist.html)

After you convert the plist, compare the values and make appropriate changes and write dictionary to plist file.

This is code snippet:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    if (url){

        NSDictionary *openedDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:url];

        // get paths from root direcory
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        // get documents path
        NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        // get the path to our Data/plist file
        NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.plist"];
        NSDictionary *originalDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

        NSMutableDictionary *newDictionary = [originalDictionary mutableCopy];
        for (NSString *key in openedDictionary) {
            if (!newDictionary[key]) {
                newDictionary[key] = openedDictionary[key];
            }
        }

        [newDictionary writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];

    }
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:url error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"error while deleting: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Why do I need to compare them? I just need to add whats in the emailed one into the main Data.plist. Sorry if I'm being really dumb, I'm new to all this

Comment: You said: "but I need to import the dictionary into my apps main Data.plist without overwriting what's already there". First check if Data.plist exists. If it doesnt just write your file there. If it does, open it and check each value if they exist. If it doesn't just write it in, if it does dont.

Comment: Ahh of course - gotcha. So I need to load the plist that's already stored in my app, compare with this one, add any keys that are different, then save it again?

Comment: Wahey! Now how to figure out how to do that ;)

Comment: I've edited above post. Just trying to get it working in the most basic sense without comparisons etc..

Comment: It doesn't appear to work - it doesn't create the Data.plist file - maybe it can't see the key or something? It's not throwing any errors..

Answer (score 1):

Try reading your main data plist in to a temporary mutable variable first. Then append the data read from the imported plist file to the temporary variable. Now write the data from temporary variable to the main data plist overwriting the whole data.